# Community Promotion Ads - 2014

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's the time of the year again, namely it is December 2013, and so we shall now refresh our Community Promotion Ads for the new year. Huh, this is the only site where this opening is similar to last years... fancy that.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- scripts packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/4009).

Comment: We've noticed an issue with voting being reversed, probably because several answers were 'ported' from last year by a single user (see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4038/my-votes-on-the-new-community-ads-get-reverted). Would it be worth noting in the standard question text that such _en masse_ copying of answers is likely to cause voting issues?

Comment: @Joseph Feel free to tack it on where you think it might be appropriate. I'll see your base and work from there if it looks like it needs any difference.

Comment: is the reappearance of this question a hint that it's time to think about the ads for 2015?  (i'm not sure there's a great deal out there that's new, but i could be overlooking something.  and i think the current selection is good.)

Answer (score 43):

[image: CTAN -- The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network]

Answer (score 42):

[image: Detexify²]

Answer (score 35):

[image: TEXample.net]

Answer (score 29):

[image: TEX Live]

Answer (score 24):

[image: TeX.SX Meta]

Answer (score 22):

[image: TeX Users Group]

Answer (score 21):

[image: The Communications of the TeX Users Group]

Answer (score 21):

[image: ConTeXt User Wiki]

Answer (score 21):

[image: Using LaTeX to Write a Ph.D Thesis by Nicola Talbot]

Comment: I really appreciate the effort, but sadly the current dimensions didn't comply with the standards, so I took the liberty of rewriting the ad from scratch. Feel free to rollback. `;)`

Comment: @texenthusiast Thank you for adding this :-) but don't worry about adding my name, it's in the mouseover.

Answer (score 20):

[image: DANTE e.v.]

Answer (score 17):

[image: Lollipop: A New Advanced TeX Format]

Comment: Dear Dr. Khalighi, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 15):

[image: Tex.SE Community Blog]

Answer (score 14):

[image: List of Tex Frequently Asked Questions on the Web]

Answer (score 12):

[image: ShareLaTeX]

Answer (score 12):

[image: writeLaTeX]

Answer (score 12):

[image: An up-to-date implementation of TeX/LaTeX for Windows]

Comment: unique selling point: Always Uptodate with _more_ `packages` and `binaries` even during _Frozen_ period of TeXLive repackaging cycle. **IMP** If possible mention, `TeX distro for Windows` for more clarity (unknown users) in logo.png.

Answer (score 11):

[image: Follow us on Twitter]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 9):

[image: LaTeX Search]

Comment: This link is a commercial one: Springer is rich enough to buy its own ad, I don't see why the community should endorse their project. Their tool might be biased and promote Springer's publication on behalf of other publications.

Comment: sadly, this appears to be simply a collection of bits that have been submitted to springer in manuscripts, unedited, and many of them show very poor quality code (like using `\bf`, `eqnarray`, etc.; it produces the intended output, but surely doesn't demonstrate recommended practices).  i don't have a problem with pointing out such a site, even if it *is* commercial, but i *do* have a prejudice against bad quality.

Answer (score 9):

[image: comp.text.tex]

Answer (score 9):

[image: How you get TeX things done]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Lowering the entry barrier to the TeX world]

Comment: TeXworks: Multi-Platform `TeX` front-end program
`Lowering the entry barrier to the TeX world`

Answer (score 6):

[image: LaTeX Community]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Academia Stack Exchange]