# My votes on the new community ads get reverted

Tags: bug, community, voting, meta

For the beginning, it's true that [I don't like the fact that we use the same community ads again and again](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2973/11002). According to that, I've decided that I'll downvote those [2014 community ads](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4009/11002) that I don't like, and upvote those that I do like. However, my votes obviously get reverted, both up-votes and down-votes, and it happens repeatedly.

One should be able to use his votes as he wants in the community ads thread. This is IMHO a bug.

Thanks

PS: According to the comments here, the problem concerns upvotes, too. It seems that we trigger the serial-voting bot because most of the answers come from one person.

Comment: Without giving any voting pattern away (although here it is probably not important), could you give us some idea of how many 'problems' you've had. I currently see a small number of '-1' votes on answers to that thread, so at least some downvotes from someone have registered.

Comment: I quite certainly voted on vast majority of ads. Currently, I can see 3 downvotes on the answers: dante, ctt and twitter. Of these, only one is mine. But I've given much more of them. Only two answers show the dark arrow for me indicating a vote. It's 1 up and 1 down.

Comment: Do you get any message when trying to vote or are the voting 'vanishing' without any feedback to you?

Comment: Unfortunately, no feedback. If I got a feedback, I would at least know what happens. But they seem to disappear with no notice at all (which can be given by the fact that no rep is associated to these votes).

Comment: @JosephWright Yes I observed same behaviour with my upvotes get retracted after some time(may be after 24 hrs I assume). I had to upvote again today. I guess , may be the system would detect as serial upvoting and reverse it back or what's happening.

Comment: OK, this sounds like a combination of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150180/the-vote-fraud-script-breaks-legitimate-polling-questions-a-serial-downvoters perhaps with the fact that the ads were mainly 'ported' from last year by a single user.

Comment: it's happening to me too.  but it does take an overnight to observe the result.  so, go back tomorrow and try again.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Off-topic: madam are you interested to place advt promo in community ads for `ams` and it's `amslatex` class and packages, since it's one of the arm of latex project.

Comment: @texenthusiast -- although the ams has rather a lot of (la)tex material that is *not* on ctan, i think that since (la)tex is not the primary function of the ams, an ams promo ad on this tex site might be more confusing than helpful.  but thanks for asking.  (if i think it's relevant, i do try to include a link to a specific ams item in comments and answers.  that's probably good enough.)

Comment: Is this still about that bidi ad? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, after trying for couple days, I came to the conclusion that **as long as you vote only 3 times a day** in the thread, **your votes won't get reverted**.

This is sort of a good news, even though I still think that votes on one person in one Q&A thread should be considered as one vote only.

Answer (score 8):

Voting on 'poll-like' questions has an issue in that voting for multiple answers is detected as 'serial voting' and is auto-reverted once a day. (See [The vote fraud script breaks legitimate polling questions - A serial downvoter's lament](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150180/the-vote-fraud-script-breaks-legitimate-polling-questions-a-serial-downvoters) for more on this.) Added to that, the fact that many of last year's answers were ported *en masse* by a single user does not help: it means that many of the answer have the same 'author' (despite the CW status).

The question is then what to do. We can try to get the underlying issue fixed, but at present that seems unlikely as the MSO thread is 'status-declined'. An 'in house' alternative is to remove the answers (or at least all of the copied-across ones) and 'start again' with a warning against mass migration. Not ideal, so the third approach is to accept people have limited votes on this thread and to leave it!

Comment: Would spreading out one's votes (to a couple a day) help circumvent this?

Comment: @Werner Well none of us know how the script actually works, so it's worth a try :-)

Comment: I decided to accept my answer since it gives a workaround :)